# How to define subclasses that differ only in one function's argument without repeating myself?

Tags: python

I'm creating classes in python like this:

```
class x(abstract_class, another_class):
    @property
    def do_something(self):
        return something('a', 'x')

class y(abstract_class, another_class):
    @property
    def do_something(self):
        return something('a', 'y')
```

This happens for many more classes. It seems long and unnecessarily repetitive, since `do_something` is not the only thing that happens within each class. Since `'x'` and `'y'` are so similar, is there any way I can create them both at once, or do anything else to stop the repetition?

Comment: `self.__class__.__name__` gets you your `'x'` or `'y'`, so `do_something(self): return something('a', self.__class__.__name__)` meets the narrow spec. However, this isn't a proper [MCVE] as given, so we can't exactly test answers.

Comment: If classes are so similar, consider extend their functionality by inheritance. This is the power of OOP - one could implement most generic functionality in parent class, and more specific - in child classes, without need to code duplication.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by passing `something()` the _name_ of a class? I ask because this seems a little like it might be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using multiple inheritance, you could "do something" like this if you don't want (or can't) modify the two existing classes you're already using as base classes. It's based on the suggestion @Charles Duffy posted in a comment, and relies on the special attribute that classes have named , not suprisingly, [`__name__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#definition.__name__).

**Note** I've also modified your code to follow [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)'s [naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions).

```
class AbstractClass: pass
class AnotherClass: pass


def something(s1, s2):
    print('something({!r}, {!r}) called'.format(s1, s2))


class Mixin:  # Yet another class.
    @property
    def do_something(self):
        something('a', self.__class__.__name__)


class X(AbstractClass, AnotherClass, Mixin):
    pass


class Y(AbstractClass, AnotherClass, Mixin):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':

    x = X()
    y = Y()

    x.do_something  # -> something('a', 'X') called
    y.do_something  # -> something('a', 'Y') called
```

Answer (score 2):

Put

```
def do_something(self):
    return something('a', self.__class__.__name__)
```

in `another_class` and they can both inherit it so that you don't have to replicate the code.

Comment: You mean `self.__class__.__name__`, right? Otherwise you're passing the class itself, not its name.

Comment: You could also add a different member to your class if you needed something besides the name and access that instead.

Comment: So doing class x(abstract_class, another_class), without doing anything else will work when the class is used?

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial on class inheritance: https://www.python-course.eu/python3_inheritance.php

Comment: @9314197, you need *something* in the body, but it can just be `pass`.

Comment: Understood. Thanks. What if I want the argument to the function to be specific to the class, but to be something other than the class name? Do I define a variable and use it in the argument?

Comment: You could define a member on your class that contains whatever information you want to pass and use that instead.  As long as it's something that self will have as an attribute, you can make it whatever you want.